# Position elements left and right on same line, or both left if not enough space

Tags: html, css

What I want:

When there's enough space, it's like this:

```css
.left{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.right{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left'>This should be on the left</div>
  <div class='right'>And this should be on the right :)</div>
</div>
```

When there's not enough space, it's like this:

```html
 <div class='parent'>
   <div class='left'>This should be on the left</div>
   <div class='right'>And this should be on the right :)</div>
</div>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: you want your lines in left and right even if not enough space? or under the first one?

Comment: @Leothelion when there're enough space, put it left and right; if there's no enough space, both line align to left

Comment: when you say 'no enough space', do you mean 'if one of the divs content is wrapped to a second line'?

Comment: then all you have to do is remove `float` property. `display: inline-block` is enough

Comment: @Venugopal In that case I cannot position the element to the right when there're enough space

Comment: oh yeah. my bad, i missed that completely..

Comment: i think its only possible with media query or else how will complier know when to remove/change float when there is no space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding width

```
.left{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%
}

.right{
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 50%
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e3xfg9te/)**

---

Use `display: table-cell` for non-width solution. And you need to insert another element to wrap the content.

```
    .parent{
   display:table;
   width:100%
 }
 .left{
  display: table-cell;
  background:grey;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.right{
  display: table-cell;
  background: blue;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.right span{
  float:right
}
```

**[DEMO 2 updated](https://jsfiddle.net/e3xfg9te/11/)**

---

Got your question ;) you can use display inline for that

```
 .left{
  display: inline;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.right{
  display:  inline;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.right span{
  float:right
}
```

**[Demo 3](https://jsfiddle.net/e3xfg9te/12/)**

Comment: I cannot set the width because the with of actual element is unknown.

Comment: @Leothelion My second fiddle is exactly what I want: I want all elements to align to left when there're not enough space

Comment: sorry text-align: justify doesn't do the job. my bad. Reverted the answer.

Comment: @Songgy m not talking about your second fiddle but second fiddle of sowmya..text is not in right... sorry for misunderstanding. but i commented here so.

Comment: @Sowmya, i think you did not get the point of op. He said when there is no enough space then second line should be under the first one but in your both demo, its not working. Plz re check.

Comment: @Sowmya Yeah LeoTheLion is correct.. the demo doesn't move the second child to the next line.

Comment: @songyy got it. Check the 3rd demo.

Comment: @Sowmya, again m saying its not possible without media query.. Please check your 3rd fiddle with one line and  you will see its not working.. still thanx for trying a lot :)

Comment: It does work with one liner but it doesn't work as expected when left div content is more. Lets hope to see if anybody can get non-media query answer :)

Answer (score 1):

#### @media

One of the approaches could use `media` css rule:

```css
.left{
  float: left;
}

.right{
  float: right;
}
/* run this in full page to check how it works */
@media all and (max-width:720px) {
  .right,.left {
    float:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left'>This should be on the left</div>
  <div class='right'>And this should be on the right :)</div>
</div>
```

#### flex

Otherwise you can use `flex` (not fully compatibile with all browsers right now):

```css
.parent {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.left, .right{
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 400px; /* line will break at min-width*2 */
  border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left'>This should be on the left</div>
  <div class='right'>And this should be on the right :)</div>
</div>
```

#### flex + js

Javascript used in order to achieve proper text-aligining.

```js
function adjustRight() {
    var right = document.getElementsByClassName("greenright")[0];
    var left = document.getElementsByClassName("greenleft")[0];
    if (left.offsetLeft == right.offsetLeft) {
        right.style.textAlign = "left";
    }
    else {
        right.style.textAlign = "right";
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", adjustRight);
window.addEventListener("resize", adjustRight);
```

```css
.parent {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
/* `green` prefix added to be sure for unique classname` */
.greenleft, .greenright{
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 400px; /* line will break at min-width*2 */
  border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='greenleft'>This should be on the left</div>
  <div class='greenright'>And this should be on the right :)</div>
</div>
```

#### js

This one is fully javascript powered example:

```js
function adjustRight() {
    var right = document.getElementsByClassName("greenright")[0];
    var left = document.getElementsByClassName("greenleft")[0];
    if (left.offsetTop == right.offsetTop) {
        right.style.float = "right";
    }
    else {
        right.style.float = "left";
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", adjustRight);
window.addEventListener("resize", adjustRight);
```

```css
/* `green` prefix added to be sure for unique classname` */
.greenleft{
  float: left;
}
.greenright {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='greenleft'>This should be on the left</div>
  <div class='greenright'>And this should be on the right :)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The media query only works on the page right? my element is just a small part of the page

Comment: @songyy Yes, media queries are designed only to work based on device. But you need to remember that you can make it work even if it works on full page width.

Comment: @songyy Edited with `flex`, it may interest you.

Comment: @Green, op don't want to use fix width.. but i think its only possible by media query.

Comment: @Leothelion Where did I fix width? There is only `mid-width` which just make it work the way OP wants to. And `max-width` in `@media` is not fixing width neither.

Comment: @Green Thanks for the flex example, it helps :) but it's not aligning the right element to the right when in the same line.

Comment: @Green, but if  op can't give width then means he too cant give min width but as in comment if he is saying yes then great :)

Comment: @songyy I have added two more examples: complete javascript one and flex mixed with javascript. Hope at least one will help!

Comment: @Green The javascript one would definitely solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.left{
  float: left;
}

.right{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left'>This should be on the left</div>
  <div class='right'>And this should be on the right :)</div>
</div>
```

**OR**

```
.left{
  display: table-cell;
  background:grey;
  float: left;
  width:50%

}

.right{
  display: table-cell;
  background:grey;
  float: right;
  width:50%
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/e3xfg9te/5/)

**OR**

```
.left{
  display: table-cell;
  background:grey;
  float: left;


}

.right{
  display: table-cell;
  background:red;
  float: left;


}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/e3xfg9te/13/)

Comment: This is exactly the first example I give. I don't want the second line to float right when there's not enough space.